# apache wont follow symlinks | 403 permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403, symlink, ubuntu-14.04

im using Ubuntu 14.04, and got problem with apache configuration:

i created a Symlink in `/var/www/html` (the apache DocRoot since Ubuntu 14.04) torwards `/home/me/myWebDirectory`

- `cd /var/www/html`
- `ln -s /home/me/myWebDirectory myWebDirectory`

but `localhost/myWebDirectory` renders a

> 403-permission denied

and in fact, `sudo -u www-data ls /home/me/myWebDirectory` returns a permission denied too

apache2.conf had following directive :

```
    <Directory /var/www>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

i changed it for `<Directory /var/www/html>`

but no result.

i tried to add the `me` user to `www-data group` with following command but it didnt help either :
`sudo usermod -a -G www-data me`

what is it that i miss ??

**EDIT**:
i changed the group of `/home/me/myWebDirectory` into www-data with rx rights, but no success either...

**NB 1:** i know there's another way to do it, while activating the apache mod_userdir and that's probably what i'll be going to do next. But first i'd like to understand how to make this "simple" solution work...

**NB 2:** i know as well i could create a VirtualHost and so on, but again, i'd like first to understand why this simple (first and temporary) solution won't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to permissions, I think you got it backwards. Adding user `me` to `www-data` does not help, you should add Apache's user to `me` users group.

Also if you changed only the group rights of `/home/me/myWebDirectory`, that is not sufficient if `/home/me` is inaccessible by `www-data` group. Make sure that users with `www-data` group can enter `/home/me` directory itself.

For more granular approach, take a look at [POSIX ACL](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/).

Comment: OK i did `deluser me www-data` then `adduser www-data me` to add apache user in the `me` group. Fyi, `ls -lR /home/me/myWebDir` returns for all : `-rwxr-xr-x me me testfile` (example given for a file obviously) while `ls -l /var/www/html` displays my Symlink : `lrwxrwxrwx root root myWebDir -> /home/me/myWebDir`. Tho the result is still the same : `403-Permission denied`

Comment: ... and how about `stat /home/me`?

Comment: returns `Accès : (0700/drwx------)` so if i get u right, i need give read access to the `me` group ?

Comment: That's what I said in my original answer. :) At minimum `chown me:www-data /home/me && chmod 710 /home/me`, or better yet, those POSIX ACLs. But, as a light-weight solution, the one I just typed up.

Comment: the lightweight solution will do it for a while, thx very very much! I put this ticket to "solved" status! Just for my general understanding, if i add the `www-data user` to the `me users group` and chmod g+r /home/me, it doesnt work, while if i chown me:www-data /home/me, it works. Does it mean apache is using more than one user?

Answer (score 0):

apache2 needs to be able to read from the beginning of the directory path

```
sudo chgrp www-data /home/username
```

add group www-data to username

```
sudo useradd -g www-data username
```

and log out and in... worked with me

if it still doesn't work use

```
sudo chgrp www-data /home/username
```

try logging out and back in... should work